# How call method to filter by year

Tags: swift

I'm making easy example. 
I'm trying to filter movies by year using func: filterByYear. 
I have an error in one line on the bottom:
'var filterYear = MovieArchive.filterByYear(1980)' Compiler info is: 'Type 'MovieArchive' has no member filterByYear’

```
import UIKit

class Movie {
    let title: String
    let director: String
    let releaseYear: Int


    init(title: String, director: String, releaseYear: Int){
        self.title = title
        self.director = director
        self.releaseYear = releaseYear
    }
}

class MovieArchive{
    var movies : [Movie]
    init(movies:[Movie]){
        self.movies = movies

    func filterByYear(year:Int) -> [Movie]{
        var filteredArray = [Movie]()
        for movie in movies{
            if movie.releaseYear == year {
                filteredArray.append(movie)
            }
        }
        return filteredArray
    }
    }
}


var newMovie1 = Movie(title: "IT", director: "S.S", releaseYear: 1980)
var newMovie2 = Movie(title: "PP", director: "O.N", releaseYear: 2003)
var moviesArray = [newMovie1, newMovie2]

var myArchive = MovieArchive(movies: moviesArray)
var filterYear = MovieArchive.filterByYear(1980)
var firstMovie = filterYear[0]
print(firstMovie)
```

Comment: First of all you meant `myArchive.filterByYear(1980)`, secondly your `filterByYear` method is nested in the `init` – you need to bring it into the main class body to call it. Lastly, you can simplify your `filterByYear` method down to `return movies.filter {$0.releaseYear == year}`. I also can't help but feel you should be using structs here, unless you really need reference semantics.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the method on the class itself, not an instance of it. You would have to create an instance of the class like this:

`let myMovieArchive = MovieArchive(movies: [`Some Array`])`

and then call the method on the instance.

`print(myMovieArchive.filterByYear)`

So in your case, call it on `myArchive`, not `MovieArchive`.

Answer (score -1):

Even though the question has been answered, you can simplify your `filterByYear` method to make it a bit more *Swifty*:

```
func filterByYear(year:Int) -> [Movie]
{
    return movies.filter({ $0.releaseYear == year })
}
```